# Sort all characters in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to solve this problem where I want to sort array of characters in a string

Problem:

**Sort an array of characters (ASCII only, not UTF8).**

**Input:** A string of characters, like a full English sentence, delimited by a newline or NULL. Duplicates are okay.

eg: This is easy

**Output:** A string of characters, in sorted order of their ASCII values. You can overwrite the existing array.

eg: Taehiisssy

**Solution Complexity:** Aim for linear time and *constant* additional space.

I know that in JavaScript you can do something like

```
const sorted = str.split('').sort().join('')
```

EDIT: I'm trying to see if I can make use of `charCodeAt(i)` method if I can get anything out of it.

But this would be O(nLogN) ^^ not linear (+extra space O(N) for split)

But in constant space, how would we sort array of characters?

Comment: Sorting is always nlogn if you are doing comparaisons. But you don't need to compare integers.  Convert the characters into their ascii codes and counting sort the integers. You don't need to use radix sort here because all the ascii codes are one after another.

Comment: Have you even attempted to do this yourself yet?

Comment: I am not sure how attempt this problem to be honest. I'm trying to get ASCII for a character by `charCodeAt(i)` and trying to see if i can get somewhere. 

PS: There's no need for -1 for learning something. It's so sad that SO discourages people when they are learning and they ask questions

Comment: @Keatinge: You are wrong. Sorting can be faster than O(n.log2n), for example this problem can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @Al Kepp What I said is correct, you are misunderstanding it. Sorting is proven to be maximum of nlogn if you are doing COMPARISIONS. Counting sort and radix sort don't do comparisions. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf

Comment: It's rather odd to mention UTF-8 here unless you are reading the input from a file encoded with UTF-8. Regardless, strings in JavaScript are sequences of UTF-16 code units, accessible via `charCodeAt`. You'd just need a comment to explain how, given the input will contain only ASCII codepoints, sorting by UTF-16 code units will be equivalent to sorting by ASCII codepoints. (ASCII is rather odd, too, as evidenced by answers that want to allow for more than 128 codepoints despite you explicitly stating ASCII.)

Comment: @Keatinge: You are wrong. Only the most common associative sorting have this limit. ASSOCIATIVE. But there are other options. The solution I had on my mind is exactly what somebody other already wrote in his answer. And it sorts in O(n) time. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Character-by-character formulate a cumulative count

```js
const s="This is easy";

// Create an array which will hold the counts of each character, from 0 to 255 (although strictly speaking ASCII is only up to 127)
let count = Array(256).fill(0);

// Look at each character in the input and increment the count for that character in the array.
for(let i=0; i<= s.length; i++) {
  c=s.charCodeAt(i);
  count[c]++;
}

let out="";
// Now scan through the character count array ...
for(let i=0; i<= 255; i++) {
// And for each character, e.g. "T", show it the number of times you saw it in the input
  for(let rep=0; rep<count[i]; rep++){
    out+=String.fromCharCode(i);
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

This only uses a constant table size, 256 numbers long (or whatever number of different symbols you wish to allow).

And the time it takes is linearly dependent on the number of characters in the input string (assuming almost no time is spent on the inner FOR loop when the count is zero for that character).

Comment: this is an implementation of Counting Sort